# I have a dataframe to split in multiple rows in R

Tags: r, split

I have a dataframe like

```
           1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

I want to split after the 4th item in the dataframe and result be like

```
           1 2 3 4 

           5 6 7 8
```

hence creating 2 rows.

Comment: is the data frame all numerics? if so just use `matrix(mtcars[1, 1:8], ncol = 4, byrow = TRUE)`, otherwise an example would help

Comment: No ther have strings as well

Comment: But this works, thanks